# React Native - Module not found when installing React native Paper

Tags: react-native, build

I'm working on a React Native project and trying to add React Native paper to my application. My app is currently working with redux, but when I try and install React Native Paper I get a build error. I'm on Mac working on iOS.

I've followed the steps on the React Native Paper site: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/getting-started.html

- yarn add react-native-paper
- yarn add react-native-vector-icons
- react-native link react-native-vector-icons

After these commands, my app is unable to build and I get a "Requiring unknown module "1090".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environment)."

I've tried yarn/npm cache clean, watchmen del, and rerunning yarn/npm install but haven't been able to get past this.

App.js (I've removed everything to just try and get this to build) -

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';


    export default class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <PaperProvider>
                  <View>
                     <Text>Hello world</Text>
                  </View>
                </PaperProvider>
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is the message in the terminal:

```
GET /index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "native/1 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/18.2.0"
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:448:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:348:35)
    at Object.getSource (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:226:21)
    at getModuleSource (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/helpers/getSourceMapInfo.js:59:17)
    at getSourceMapInfo (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/helpers/getSourceMapInfo.js:50:42)
    at _toConsumableArray.concat.filter.filter.map.module (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapObject.js:52:7)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at fullSourceMapObject (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapObject.js:51:6)
    at /Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1165:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
::1 - - [04/Apr/2019:00:39:30 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "native/1 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/18.2.0"
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:448:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:348:35)
    at Object.getSource (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:226:21)
    at getModuleSource (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/helpers/getSourceMapInfo.js:59:17)
    at getSourceMapInfo (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/helpers/getSourceMapInfo.js:50:42)
    at _toConsumableArray.concat.filter.filter.map.module (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapObject.js:52:7)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at fullSourceMapObject (/Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/sourceMapObject.js:51:6)
    at /Users/peyton/Desktop/Projects/MoviePass/native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1165:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

And in the iPhone preview:

```
Requiring unknown module "1090".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environment).


loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:224:31
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:170340:42
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:169329:37
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:163396:36
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:157171:40
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:157077:29
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:88467:38
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
<unknown>
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:1367:48
loadModuleImplementation
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:265:14
guardedLoadModule
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:153:47
global code
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:170659:4
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to link react-native-paper with your react-native project. So just try out this command and it may fix your problem.

```
react-native link react-native-paper 
    or just
react-native link
```